# Не работает систамная кнопка Back когда SearchView активен

Tags: android, xamarin, android-search-view

Есть вот такой `SearchView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"  />
</menu>
```

При активации этого `searchView` (появляется поле для ввода текста поиска и клавиатура), по нажатию на системную кнопку андройда назад, первым делом клавиатура скрывается (`SearchView` остаётся активным), а по второму нажатию SearchView должен скрываться. Но никакого результата не происходит.

`OnBackPressed()` активити - не вызывается в этом случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прибегнул к лайфхакам, т.к. действующего способа я не нашёл.

Создал кастомный `SearchView` в котором заоверайдил метод `DispatchKeyEventPreIme`:

```
public override bool DispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back && e.Action == KeyEventActions.Up)
        {
            BackButtonPressed?.Invoke(this, new KeyEventArgs(true,Keycode.Back, e));
        }
        return base.DispatchKeyEventPreIme(e);
    }
```

В нём отлавливаю нажатие кнопки бэк и фаерю своё событие.
На вьюшке отлавливаю это событие и проверяю открыта ли клавиатура , если да - делаю searchView невидимым, а затем видимым (других способов как потерять фокус я не нашёл). И при следующем нажатии на бэк, у нас покажет что клавиатура спрятана.

```
private void BackButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var imm = (InputMethodManager)Activity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
        if (!imm.IsAcceptingText)
        {
            Activity.OnBackPressed();
        }
        _searchView.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
        _searchView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
```